# replace each pixel by median of its 4 neighbourhood

Tags: image, matlab, digital

i made this code can anybody tell me is this right how can i verify it.

```
I=imread('cameraman.tif');
[M N]=size(I);
for i=2:M-1
    for j=2:N-1
        x=I(i-1,j);
        y=I(i+1,j);
        z=I(i,j-1);
        zz=I(i,j+1);
        A=[x y z zz];
        J(i,j)=median(A);
    end
end
```

Comment: Create a simple matrix, print it. Pass it to the function. Print it. See if it worked. Furthermore, you can pass it an image, if the image is blurred, probably you did it right.

Comment: Do you have access to the image processing tool box by any chance because: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on Code Review btw: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but your code does look correct. You should avoid using `i` and `j` as variable names in matlab though as they are keywords for `sqrt(-1)`. Also for your edges you could take median of 3 neighbours instead of just leaving them out completely.

Comment: Normally you'd include the center pixel too.

Comment: @Dan - Even without the image processing toolbox you can use [filter2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html) with `h = [0, 1/4, 0; 1/4, 0, 1/4; 0, 1/4, 0]` or, if you want to include the central pixel, `h = [0, 1/5, 0; 1/5, 1/5, 1/5; 0, 1/5, 0]`.

Comment: @beaker: That is an average filter, not a median filter.

Comment: @Junuxx - haha... oops, you're right :) Too many distractions this morning...

Answer (score 1):

In general, the only way you can discover whether it does what you expect is to try whether it works. @Maroun already described this.

Here are some of the things I noticed:

- I believe the code has no techical problems.
- I am no expert on the topic but it would surprise me if you don't want to consider the middle point `I(i,j)` when determining the median. Now you just check left right up and down. Besides this you may want to evaluate the upleft upright downleft and downright. This is a choice however.
- Another thing to notice is that currently your result will be smaller than the original image. Probably you want to start with `J=I` or `J = NaN(size(I));`